# what platform choose for mysql

Tags: mysql

which platform (operation system) better to choose for best MySql performance? windows or linux?

coonections pool for websites use or not?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a choice I recommend putting it on a Linux box. The reason being that the Linux version is developed first and then ported. Whenever possible I like to install software on its "native" platform. I just seem to have less trouble that way.

Answer (score 1):

It's essentially whatever your Ops team and hardware vendor can support, but one word of warning:

DO NOT run MySQL on a 32-bit system. Never. You will run out of address space then have a world of pain migrating.

Connection pooling isn't that bad, but you may get just as good performance without it, and it adds significant risk of bugs - connections can get left in a bad (or funny) state which breaks subsequent requests, often quite subtly. I would recommend not using pooling or persistent connections (e.g. on Apache).

On the other hand if you have a long-running daemon process, IT may want to hold connections open for its own use, as nobody "else" will use them.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll be using a dedicated server, go for Linux - much easier to disable all the other stuff you won't need for a MySQL server; also, easier to tweak all kinds of parameters (TCP/IP stack comes to mind).

Answer (score 0):

In general I suggest Linux. However if all your sysadmins only know windows, then forcing linux on them is a bad idea. However if you **are** the sysadmin team, and you don't mid either, go with Linux.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Linux, however. This all boils down to the system administrator you have available, if he does not know Linux, then what?

If your SA has never touched Linux, I would not recommend going to that platform. Hosting Linux on a production environment if you're a windows guy, is not like playing around with Ubuntu at home.